# How can i set a null value in json body to update a database table?

Tags: c#, json

I am call an endpoint wit a json body as follow :

```
{
 "OrderId": 123,
 "OrderItem": 100,
 "OrderAmount": null,
}
```

The endpoint is called , but the OrderAmount column in the db is not set to NULL.
The column is of type (int, null)
How can i set the value in the db to NULL from the json body ?

Comment: And how did your json body get into the database? You should show and tell.

Comment: JSON isn't a database language. Your application's code is converting that JSON into INSERT or UPDATE commands. We can't guess what the code does or what's wrong.

Comment: What does `the OrderAmount column in the db is not set to NULL.` mean? Do you get a `0` instead of NULL when inserting a new record? Or did you expect to UPDATE an existing record with NULL? How do you make modifications to the database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your OrderAmount in your database set to NULL, when you created the table?
usually if column type is INT, then it will be set to 0 instead of null.
you need to change type to VARCHAR.

try pass an empty String "", and see what happens?

Comment: This should be a comment at best. Even then it would be a very bad idea - storing numbers as text always *causes* sever problems, it never helps. What if the code stores `potato`? Or `123,000`? Is that 123 or 123000? You have no idea any more. What about whitespace?

Comment: `usually if column type is INT, then it will be set to 0 instead of null.` never. If the column isn't nullable, trying to insert a NULL will raise an error, even if it the column has a default value. If it's nullable, you get a NULL, even if it has a default value.

Comment: @Elbashir Saror thankyou inserting 0 works

Comment: @Tracey no it doesn't, because 0 isn't NULL. If passing `0` ends up inserting NULL you have *another* bug. You still haven't posted any relevant code or even explained what the problem is, what you expected